# Navigating Google search results using keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, google-search

Some will think this is not related to programming but I think it is, because most of the time when I encounter programming issues I search on Google to find solutions or ways to do what I plan to do before I start writing it from scratch. Let's face it, we all copy pasters...

I don't like to remove my hands from the keyboard. Google had a feature after you submit a query and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will start navigating within the search results. Most likely because they had a tabindex attribute which was was removed.

Does anyone know why sometimes this works and sometimes it doesn't? I'm starting to think I should create a Chrome app that will add the tab index to the results, but I don't want to do it before I am 100% sure this feature was removed.

Comment: Seems to work consistently for me.

Comment: is the first tab click bring you to the first results with little arrow on the right of the results?

Comment: Yes, pressing tab brings the arrow the the left of the first result.

Comment: This is broken again since 2 weeks ago 1/Jun/2017. Tried enabling instant search and tried changing to English and nothing works. Broken on firefox + chrome, windows + linux :(

Comment: @ihadanny I am using chrome 58.0.3029.110 on MAC OS and it works fine to me, I had issue also few days ago and I change my search settings one again and it working now, I am not sure they might have some expiration to your search preferences, try to change , save ,change again, and save.

Comment: tried Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2, reset my search preferences, saved and nothing works :( I don't get it - how come they switch off such a useful feature and no one notices???

Comment: its working again! Nothing changed on my side but suddenly its working. probably something related with the "co.il" version of google search, as I noticed that the new annoying "make this your homepage?" dialog is also gone.

Comment: To me it always seemed tied to Instant Results, and Google has announced it is removing Instant Results. I have been unable to make this work afterwards.

Comment: So the shortcuts are no longer available? It stopped working for me day or so ago and I'm looking for the solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for help with a website and is not a programming question.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

As of 2017-07-31, [Google removed this feature entirely from search](http://searchengineland.com/google-dropped-google-instant-search-279674).

I created the open source [Web Search Navigator extension](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator) to fix this and add extra features (like configurable keyboard shortcuts).

See [installation instructions](https://github.com/infokiller/web-search-navigator#installation).

Hope you find it useful, but in any case - feedback is welcome!

Comment: This is great. Also like the `vimium` you mentioned in the `issue` area. Really making navigation inside chrome with keyboard so much easier.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: The link about Google removing this feature is about instant search—doesn't seem mention keyboard shortcuts at all.

Comment: Right, but there was some strange dependency between them (see talsibony's answer below)

Comment: @mancze: Looks like JohnnyW finished his Firefox extensions. I'm using it and it works great. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-google-search-navigator/

Comment: @JohnnyW The chrome webstore link no longer works!

Comment: @MaryamHnr see the installation instructions link I added to the answer.

Comment: Any way to do this on Firefox?

Comment: @PaulRBerg yes it's also available for firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-search-navigator/

Comment: Are there any similar extensions for YouTube search results?

Comment: @Bip901 the latest version of Web Search Navigator has optional YouTube support

Answer (score 38):

Finally I manage to figure it out!!!
if you are using google search settings in Hebrew this awesome feature is not available, so I changed the search settings to english and it works great!

https://www.google.com/preferences

---

small update thanks @Sanook it looks like the instant results also need to be enabled, I checked it several times and seems that lang should be defined as English and instant results need to be enabled.

---

**2017-07-31 update**

It looks like now google abandoned the instant results feature which is causing the whole search navigation via keyboard to be unsupported.
I posted in their forum and hope it will comeback sometime...
 [search-forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/d486kEncY0k;context-place=forum/websearch)

Comment: For me, I had to enable instant result !

Comment: It works for me also if I disable the instant result, once I change it to hebrew again this feature is gone, so it must be related to the language settings...

Comment: Looks like the changes I made was not took affect to check your comment immediately and I find out that you are right so I changed the answer, thank your for pointing it out!, so it seems like it depends on the language and instant results configuration.

Comment: For me, it sometimes doesn't work when I'm logged into a Google account.

Comment: "instant results need to be enabled" did it for me. Thanks!

Comment: *Instant Results*. Yeah finally! But this sucks. I hate instant results.

Comment: enabling _Instant Results_ did it for me as well!

Comment: I had to switch language from French to English as well, using the link provided in this answer (section "Languages").

Comment: Instant results no longer exists, so this solution no longer works.

Comment: @ChristianRavn Its seems that you are right Google disable this feature and I cant navigate search results, hope they will fix it

Comment: @talsibony Unfortunately I think it is gone for good, since Google is focusing heavily on mobile interaction. We can always hope though and I'll post a new comment if I find a way to do it :). Until then you should probably edit the answer and say that the method suggested no longer works.

Comment: Yea,but it look like the navigation feature was dropped by mistake, it was not supposed to be related to instant search from first place.

Comment: @ChristianRavn Edited my answer, and posted question in google search forum, I dont know if it will get to someone there by worth tying..

Answer (score 6):

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-keyboard-sh/iobmefdldoplhmonnnkchglfdeepnfhd/reviews

Chrome plugin which emulates what Google Instant results used to do. TABing between results is back :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is also a Chrome Extension called RESULTER, which does not solve the exact problem described in the question, but provides good search results navigation anyway.

You can download it from Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resulter-shortcuts-for-se/chojfhfgbdaeokblbdeahgbijodikdpk

Official website: https://getresulter.com

Answer (score 0):

The down arrow works for me. Pressing the down arrow once moves focus to the first result then again will continue through the results.

Tab will gradually cycle through items on the page: Google logo, search box, menu items then eventually to the search results.

`Chrome Version 51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)
OSX 10.5.5
Macbook Pro`

Comment: I checked and also down arrow key is working, but still you must have Google Instant predictions enabled.