# Navigating Google search results using keyboard shortcuts without "instant search" feature

Tags: search, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

Google has dropped the instant search feature lately (in the news: [the verge](https://www.theverge.com/2017/7/26/16034844/google-kills-off-instant-search-for-mobile-consistency)).

So, **without the instant search** how to navigate through the results of a normal google search only with the keyboard?

Note, that with the instant search this question is already answered on [this Stackoverflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28523807/navigating-google-search-results-using-keyboard-shortcuts).

Comment: I would like to use Chrome, maybe there is an extension?

Comment: I think, I was too focused on Google. Because Bing and DuckDuckGo already have this keyboard functunality working. Besides that, DuckDuckGo has many more customizations and features than Google search. So, Bye Google!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a very simple [open source extension](https://github.com/infokiller/google-search-navigator) to fix this and make keyboard shortcuts configurable.

You can install it from the Chrome Webstore:
 [Google Search Navigator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-navigator/cohamjploocgoejdfanacfgkhjkhdkek).

Hope you find it useful, but in any case- feedback is welcome!

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the chrome extension, that I overlooked.

Comment: Now, Google Search is usable again. Thanks. And I have make a new Issue. It's more an Feature Request, see in your Repo.

Comment: Wonderful! Now I just feel like the only thing missing is to be able to go back to the search field with the keyboard. Ideally by going "up" when on the first search result.

Comment: Hi, is there an option to open a new tab in the background? i used to love searching stuff, and then opening a bunch of results in multiple background tabs. is this possible somehow with your extension? thanks!

Comment: @FelixKreuk do `Ctrl+Enter`/`Ctrl+Space` do what you want?

Comment: @JohnnW it does open a new tab, but in the foreground. It would be great if I had the ability to open it in the background if I wanted (e.g. a separate keyboard binding to open a new tab in the background).

Answer (score -1):

You may find [Chrome extension RESULTER](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-search-shortcuts-r/chojfhfgbdaeokblbdeahgbijodikdpk) good for this. It's basically a Google Search productivity extension.

Apart from bringing back the Tab and Arrows navigation keyboard shortcuts on Google Search results page, it introduces a special panel with search results. You can use Alt+A shortcut to open search results list and navigate from there, without going back to the Google Search page. It makes search flow more natural.

You can also focus on the search box with Alt+S keyboard shortcut.